# AWS-S3 orb - Circle CI - Unexpected argument(s): arguments

Tags: amazon-s3, circleci, circleci-2.0

I'm getting the following error in my build:

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
# Error calling workflow: 'build-deploy'
# Error calling job: 'build_test_es'
# Error calling command: 'aws-s3/sync'
# Unexpected argument(s): arguments
# 
# -------
# Warning: This configuration was auto-generated to show you the message above.
# Don't rerun this job. Rerunning will have no effect.
false
Exited with code 1
```

This is how my config.yml file looks, I've supressed some parts.

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  aws-s3: circleci/aws-s3@1.0.0
jobs:
  build_test_es:  
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10.15
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker

      - run:
          name: NPM install
          command: |
            cd app 
            pwd
            npm install

      - run:
          name: NPM build
          command: |
            cd app 
            pwd
            npm run build

      - run: mkdir bucket && echo "lorum ipsum" > bucket/build_asset.txt
      - aws-s3/sync:
          from: bucket
          to: 's3://my-s3-bucket-name/prefix'
          arguments: |
            --acl public-read \
            --cache-control "max-age=86400"
          overwrite: true
```

As you can see I'm using the default command from the docs:
https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/circleci/aws-s3#commands-sync

Is the orb broken? Have I misspleded something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it by updating the orb. Nice way to waste time.

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  aws-s3: circleci/aws-s3@1.0.3
```